# AngularJS OR BackboneJS from Webservice point of view

Tags: rest, angularjs, backbone.js, soap

We are trying to rebuild an app using Backbone or Angular JS. Main criteria for selecting either of them would be:

The Java script Framework should be able to make calls via SOAP as well as REST.

My question is based on the criteria's which framework should I be choosing? I know angular as well as Backbone are good for REST web service. I am not really sure how well they do when we are trying to make SOAP calls. Not much help online either. Has anyone successfully implemented SOAP calls via Angular or Backbons JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone.sync method can be easily overriden to make SOAP calls, but it will fall apart if your SOAP service manages anything else than resources, as REST calls in Backbone are made on behalf of either models or collections of models that support the classic CRUD semantics. As for AngularJS, I haven't used it enought to provide you with an informed answer.